# Unable to open specific JAR file in Java Code

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I'm not able to open **my** JAR file using the following code. Though, I'm able to open **other** JAR files.

```
try {  
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("myPlugin.jar"));  
     }  
       catch(Exception exception) {  
        exception.printStackTrace();  
        }    
      }
```

I don't know if I'm exporting the JAR file incorrectly or some error in the Manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: Reader
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of exception?  Does it not throw an exception but the jar appears empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try putting in the full path to the file

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

It looks like the error was not specifying the full path. Though, not specifying the full path worked for another JAR file. Any ideas?

Comment: Reply to other comments above...There were no errors or exceptions, and the program compiles just fine. I am running it from a Groovy Console.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking Windows to invoke your jar-file.  Can you invoke it from CMD.EXE?

```
java -jar myPlugin.jar
```

My guess is that you get an error, which is silently discarded.  Running from CMD.EXE will show you the problem.

Comment: The JAR file runs from the Command Prompt as well. No issues here.